# Jquery works on one domain, not the other - with *identical* code

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, drive

I'm using the Dynamic Drive Jquery image magnifier in my page http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex4/imagemagnify.htm.

I have the page loaded on two seperate domains - the HTML is identical and all links (css/js/images) are full http strings to my testing server.  The header looks like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://slim.bobpitch.com/DS/js/jquery.magnifier.js">
```

However, on one domain the page loads perfectly, but the jquery doesn't work, on the other domain the jquery works, but the page formatting is corrupted.  The error I'm getting on the first page is:

```
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'magnify' of undefined
```

Which refers to this piece of script:

```
    jQuery.fn.imageMagnify=function(options){
var $=jQuery
return this.each(function(){ //return jQuery obj
    var $imgref=$(this)
    if (this.tagName!="IMG")
        return true //skip to next matched element
    if (parseInt($imgref.css('width'))>0 && parseInt($imgref.css('height'))>0 || options.thumbdimensions){ //if image has explicit width/height attrs defined
        jQuery.imageMagnify.magnify($, $imgref, options)
    }
    else if (this.complete){ //account for IE not firing image.onload
        jQuery.imageMagnify.magnify($, $imgref, options)
    }
    else{
        $(this).bind('load', function(){
            jQuery.imageMagnify.magnify($, $imgref, options)
        })
    }
})
```

I am utterly baffled, and only an enthusiast CSS tinkerer, what I know about <s>java</s> JavaScript could be written on the back of a very small thing. Why does it work on one domain and not the other?

Comment: You're missing the `</script>` at the end of the second script include. Is that just a copy-and-paste error?

Comment: It could just be a cache issue. Clear your cache and try both pages again.

Comment: *"...what I know about java could be written on the back of a very small thing..."* LOL, including the fact that this is *JavaScript*, not Java (they're very different languages). :-) I've fixed the tags for you and edited that part of the question.

Comment: An important note: `Java` and `JavaScript` are *completely* different language and technologies. Also, it is better not to put "thanks" messages on your questions on this site--show your thanks by upvoting good answers. This makes your question easier to read and helps both you and the people answering.

Comment: i think you are not getting acces to your script file on other server.. This may be an issue...

Comment: Have you checked the Net tab of Firebug to make sure the js file is actually loading?

Comment: T.J - I appreciate the edit.
Tikhon, et all - Noted. Caches have been cleared and the js file is actually loading.

Answer (score 2):

check whether you are having internet in both machines. can you access http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js from both machines. the reason for this error is , when you try to call `magnify` jQuery is not loaded. so you cannot call plugin without jQuery. or if you register jquery after plugin it will reset all the plugins loaded already

Comment: Nailed it and found the solution - thanks for the pointer. The problem was I was using the HTML5 Boilerplate which has script loading at the bottom of the page, I had including conflicting script at the top. I removed the conflicting link for http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js and everything works just fine on both sites. 

So - definite wetware error there

Comment: I don't have the reputation to upvote - I clicked 'yes' on the "Was this helpful" question - sorry if showing bad manners, just being a noob

Answer (score 0):

I think that the fact that the error is in the call to magnify() means that the  magnifier has problems loading

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://slim.bobpitch.com/DS/js/jquery.magnifier.js">
```

otherwise you would get an error that complains that jQuery is not a function, so check that there are no problems in loading that file from the domain (check in firebug if the script loaded correctly)

Answer (score 0):

Check if application is referring to different versions of jquery files